# Adding data to an ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arraylist

I've got the following:

```
// Begin the WebRequest to the desired RSS Feed
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

// Convert the RSS Feed into an XML document
Stream rssStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();

rssDoc.Load(rssStream);

// This uses an XPath expression to get all nodes that fall 
// under this path.
XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");
ArrayList returnArrayList = new ArrayList();

CharData cd = new CharData();
for (int i = 0; i < rssItems.Count; i++)
{
    cd.CharacterName = rssItems[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
    cd.CharacterID = rssItems[i].Attributes["characterID"].Value;
    cd.CorporationID = rssItems[i].Attributes["corporationID"].Value;
    cd.CorporationName = rssItems[i].Attributes["corporationName"].Value;
}
this.richTextBox1.Text = cd.CharacterName+"\r\n"+cd.CharacterID+"\r\n"+cd.CorporationID+"\r\n"+cd.CorporationName+"\r\n";
```

CharData Class:

```
class CharData
{
    private string _charName;
    private string _charID;
    private string _corporationID;
    private string _corpName;

    public string CharacterName
    {
        get { return _charName; }
        set { _charName = value; }
    }
    public string CharacterID
    {
        get { return _charID; }
        set { _charID = value; }
    }
    public string CorporationID
    {
        get { return _corporationID; }
        set { _corporationID = value; }
    }
    public string CorporationName
    {
        get { return _corpName; }
        set { _corpName = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, how do I add multiple chars data the system and retrieve them later?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - and it's not clear why you're not using non-generic collections, either. Are you stuck on .NET 1.1?

Comment: Is your question about on how to add CharData instance to the returnArrayList  list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare new `CharData` inside the for loop, and then add it to array. like:

```
List<CharData> charDataList = new List<CharData>();

for (int i = 0; i < rssItems.Count; i++)
{
    CharData cd = new CharData();

    cd.CharacterName = rssItems[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
    cd.CharacterID = rssItems[i].Attributes["characterID"].Value;
    cd.CorporationID = rssItems[i].Attributes["corporationID"].Value;
    cd.CorporationName = rssItems[i].Attributes["corporationName"].Value;

    charDataList.Add(cd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `ArrayList` when possible because it's not typesafe and is only kept for backward compatibility. Since .NET 2.0, generic `List<T>` should be used instead.

I believe you're trying to do this:

```
var returnItems = new List<CharData>();
foreach (var rssItem in rssItems) {
    returnItems.Add(new CharData {
        CharacterName = rssItem.Attributes["name"].Value,
        CharacterID = rssItem.Attributes["characterID"].Value,
        CorporationID = rssItem.Attributes["corporationID"].Value,
        CorporationName = rssItem.Attributes["corporationName"].Value
    });
}
```

Also, [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx) is the preferred API for extracting data from XML since .NET 3.5—and it's simpler, too. You can rewrite your sample as follows:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(rssStream);
var returnItems = (from rssItem in doc.Descendants("row")
                   select new CharData {
                       CharacterName = rssItem.Attribute("name"),
                       CharacterID = rssItem.Attribute("characterID"),
                       CorporationID = rssItem.Attribute("corporationID"),
                       CorporationName = rssItem.Attribute("corporationName")
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use generics:

```
System.Collection.Generic.List<CharData> returnArrayList = new System.Collection.Generic.List<CharData>();
```

In any case(generic or the current non generic) you can add item using

```
returnArrayList.Add(cd);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your objects have an ID so a Dictionary might be better if you need to access by ID. Alternatively, if each CharData is displayed in it's own control item, such as a gridrow, you could link the CharData object to the control's .Tag property.